# couldn't cast an object array to another type array

Tags: java

been pulling my hair for nights when I get an ClassCastException as I try to cast an object type to another object type.... I'm that sure that this code will work because all objects are are subclasses of the Object class... but somehow i get this exception...some help guys?

Sorry guys..not to be confused with the Original ArrayList, I'm learning Java programming, and practicing on casting object arrays... the exception is at line 8, where I casted the object array to a weapon array type... sorry for any form of trolling...

```
public class ArrayList {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        weapon[] weapons = new weapon[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < weapons.length; i++) {
            weapons[i] = new weapon(i);
        }
        weapons = (weapon[]) arrayList.add(weapons, 
                new weapon(weapons.length + 1, "mp5"));
    }

    public Object[] add(Object[] targetObjectList, Object add){
        Object[] oldList = new Object[targetObjectList.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < oldList.length; i++){
            oldList[i] = targetObjectList[i];
        }
        Object[] newList = new Object[oldList.length+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++) {
            newList[i] = oldList[i];
        }
        newList[newList.length - 1] = add;
        return newList;
    }

}//end arrayList class

class weapon {
    String name;
    int id;
    public weapon(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        name = "weapon";
    }

    public weapon(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code confused me with java's original ArrayList class, I would consider this as a really bad naming style. P.S. even methods are (.add).

Comment: I am just few days on StackOverflow, and it seems that there are a lot of trolls here.

Comment: You make your question hard to answer by not telling us where you are getting the exception, and not posting the stacktrace.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code.  You have created an array of 5 weapons.  After that are you simply trying to create a 6th weapon and place it in your array.  You could use a java.util.ArrayList<weaopn> to accomplish this and get rid of your add method.  You could also keep a static nextId in your weapon class so that it could generate its own id.  But you might want to explain what you are trying to do.  Otherwise you will get very complex and slightly off the mark answers. (not that contravariance is a bad concept..)

Comment: @Op De Cirkel - 1) who are you talking about, and 2) how is this relevant?  IMO, this is just another question where the OP hasn't bothered to provide enough information.

Comment: @Stephen I see a lot of questions that seem to me intentionally confusing

Comment: sorry ...the exception is at line 8, where i cast an object array to another type.. sorry for the bad naming style...i'm trying to learn java programming about more on casting and try to create a method of adding objects in an array without the use of ArrayList

Comment: @Op De Cirkel - have you heard of Hanlon's Razor?  See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor.  Though to be fair to the OP and others like him, the problem usually not *stupidity* ... but an inability to write clearly and/or lack of understanding of subject matter.  If you find that hard to deal with, you are probably hanging out on the wrong website!

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: What you see is a lot of questions by people who are not native English speakers, or who have just started out programming and are still shaky on many concepts, or who are not used to communicating questions to people who are not sitting alongside them and know in advance what the problem is about. So instead of accusing them of trolling, I suggest that you instead point out how they could improve their question. Also, see [Jeff Atwood's opinion on the subject](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html).

Comment: @Stephen - thanks for pointing Hanlon Razor. It is interesting, since people usually think that can distinguish these things intuitively

Answer (score 1):

A `weapon` is an `Object`; therefore, we may treat an array af `weapon` as an array of `Object`. However, not all `Object`s are `weapon`s; therefore, an array of `Object` may not be treated as an array of `weapon` - unless the thing that seems to be an array of `Object` really was an array of `weapon` to begin with. Because of this, your approach will become difficult. You could try

```
weapon[] newList = new weapon[oldList.length+1];
```

instead, but then you'd need to change all the arrays to be of type `weapon[]`, and the method wouldn't become general (which I suppose is your goal). However, if you want a method that can add an element to any kind of array, you should use *generics* instead.

P.S. If you are learning about programming and arrays, writing such an `add()` method is a good exercise - but if you "just want it to work", you should use `ArrayList` instead, which does the whole job of adding for you.

Comment: hmm...my goal is to change the returned object array to a weapon type array..is it possible to do it without using ArrayList?

Comment: @Shizumaru18: Not if you start out with `new Object[oldList.length+1]`, because then you get an array which knows that it is an `Object` array. You can put as many `weapon`s into it as you like, but it will still be an `Object` array. Because it is an `Object` array, it would actually allow you to put anything into it, say, a `Car` or an `Apple`, and therefore, Java won't let you treat it as a `weapon` array. My advice would be to drop the use of `Object` and `Object[]` in `add()`, and use `weapon` and `weapon[]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are subclass of `Object`. You cannot cast `Object[]` to `weapon[]`. Here is a generic solution for your problem:

```
weapons = (weapon[])arrayList.add(weapons, new weapon(weapons.length + 1, "mp5"),weapon.class);
```

and

```
public <T> T[] add(T[] targetObjectList, T add, Class<T> c) {
    T[] oldList = (T[])Array.newInstance(c, targetObjectList.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++) {
        oldList[i] = targetObjectList[i];
    }
    T[] newList = (T[])Array.newInstance(c, oldList.length + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++) {
        newList[i] = oldList[i];
    }

    newList[newList.length - 1] = add;

    return newList;

}
```

Note: Follow `Java Naming Conventions`. Avoid `Java API` class names as your class name.

Comment: Also System.arraycopy() is your friend; cast to T[].

Comment: @karamkaze: yes. but i just fixed the cast issue.

Answer (score 0):

- `Object o = new Foo()`. This is ok. Foo is Object. As `Foo extends Object`
- `Foo f = new Object()` Not OK, Object is NOT Foo (Compiler error)
- `Foo f = (Foo)(new Object())` `- ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is known as [contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).  The inherent problem in your code is that the ARRAY that you are creating in the add function is an array of Objects (regardless of what those objects actually end up being).

If you were to do the following, your code would work.  I think that you need to work with generics in this sense (look at the actual ArrayList class as it already implements this).

```
...snip...
    Object[] newList = new weapon[oldList.length+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++) {
        newList[i] = oldList[i];
    }
    newList[newList.length - 1] = add;
    return newList;
...snip...
```

Here is an example code that works much as you are anticipating it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] i = (Integer[])Test.get();

    }

    public static Object[] get() {
        Object[] o = new Object[20];
        for(int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            o[i] = new Integer(0);
        }
        return o;
        }
}
```

ArrayList has a method .toArray(T[] a) which will return an enlarged array size containing your new elements.  So how does this contravariance work?  Through the java.reflect package.  This is a very small excerpt of how it actually works (there are a few different packages that work together to get down to this.)

```
...Object[] function(Object[] typearray) {
    Object[] o = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(typearray.getClass().getComponentType(), 20);
    ...fill...
    return o;
}
```

The reason you must do this is because the ARRAY (since everything in Java are objects) is an Object itself, then an Array of Objects cannot be upcasted to an Array of Integers.  If you downcasted from an array of integers to an array of Objects (as shown in this above example) and then upcasted again from an Array of Objects to an Array of Integers (because we never dropped the underlying class of it being an Array of Integers).